# angularjs custom Directive to manage filter chain with checkboxes list, need ng-change

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I wrote a directive for managing some filter chain based on checkboxes list the directive took as input a list of object, display the lists (as list of checkboxes) based on a key (other input) and as output I need to have a list of the selected item).
This is the code of my directive

```
directive('filterPanel', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    trasclude: true,
    scope: {
     availableFilters: "=filterlist",
     ngModel: "=",
     filterField: '=filterfield',
     title: '@title',
     panelclass: "@panelclass",
     previousSelection: "=previousselectionlist",
     selectOne: "=selectone"
   },
   templateUrl: 'panel-filter.tpl.html',
   controller: function($scope) {
      if (angular.isUndefined($scope.filterField)) {
        $scope.filterField = 'area';
      }
      $scope.clearSelection = function() {
        $scope.ngModel.splice(0, $scope.ngModel.length);
     };
     $scope.toggleSelection = function(filterOption) {
        var idx = $scope.ngModel.indexOf(filterOption);
         if (idx > -1) {
          $scope.ngModel.splice(idx, 1);
         } else {
           if ($scope.selectOne) {
             $scope.ngModel.splice(0, $scope.ngModel.length);
             $scope.ngModel.push(filterOption);
           } else {
             $scope.ngModel.push(filterOption);
           }
        }
     }
   }
 }
});
```

I know that there is a problem if the availableFilters list (passed from the outside) changes the change will not be propagate to the result list ( I was thinking to add a watch on the availableFilters list for handling that.

but the real problem is that I would like to use ng-change on the directive in order to know if the user select something or not but is not clear to me how to do that.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25973789/3532610)  and watched the plunker but still I don't understand how to trigger the ng-change in my directive.

here a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RH9KtWvwagWN7N4GtfY3?p=preview)