# How to use ng-change function in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make auto-complete, for this I am using tags-input. Directive name is my-directive, Inside controller I am trying to call `selectUser` function, but it is not working.

In auto-complete, you have to type 4 letters, like: john, then I will show options..

**View**

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <my-directive  apipoint="customerApi" modeldisplay="tags.selected"  ng-model="tags.selected" change="selectUser(tags.selected)"></my-directive>
  </body>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope){     
  $scope.tags = {};
  $scope.tags.selected = [];
  $scope.customerApi = ['tags.json'];
  $scope.selectUser = function(foo)  {
    $scope.aux = foo;
    alert();
  };
});
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("myDirective", ['$http',function($http){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template : 'Here Use tag-input: <tags-input ng-model="modeldisplay"'+
     'ng-change="change(modeldisplay)">'+
     '<auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>'+
     '</tags-input>',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope : {
      modeldisplay: "=",
      apipoint: "="
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
      scope.loadTags = function(query) {
         return $http.get(scope.apipoint[0]);
      };
      scope.change = function(item){
        ctrl.$setViewValue(item);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

**DEMO/Now Working **

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/f7MZuNaDWIFatLPZobhN?p=preview)

One more thing Is my approach I right?, Reason Behind is that, In Angularjs View, I want to use auto-complete directive oneline, I want to make it as generic approach...

Comment: In auto-complete, you have to type 4 letters, like: john, then I will show options..

Comment: you need to call passed function in `scope.change` function using `$scope.$apply(function)` -  `scope.change = function(item){
      $scope.$apply(item())
      }`

Comment: @Anita, Thanks for reply, I didn't get it, could you elaborate more on it..

Comment: @Anita not working..

Comment: i hve made changes to you plunker added that plunker link in answer. Plz comment if anything is not clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes you should do to run the controller function.

Here is the working plunker [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tAssYy2Zwh1BkVPYidRN?p=preview)

1. You were using third party directive that doesn't provide ng-change on that. Yes but it provides `on-tag-added="change1(modeldisplay)`. So `ng-change` was not working.
2. You have passed function in the **change** attribute of you `my-directive` and again there was another **change function** in your directive scope, that was creating misunderstanding.
3. You were accessing passed function using **scope** but you have not mentioned that in directive **isolated scope**. That's why that passed function was not accessible in directive scope.

Comment: Could you tell, Is my approach I right?, Reason Behind is that, In Angularjs View, I want to use auto-complete directive oneline, I want to make it as generic approach...

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/b9T4locYfX0qBWImimZK?p=preview)

Directive changes:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get(scope.apipoint[0]);
  };
  scope.updateModel = function(item) {
    ctrl.$setViewValue(item);
  };
},
controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('modeldisplay', function(newVal) {
    $scope.updateModel(newVal);
  });
}],
```

Read this if you need more explanation:

[How to implement an ng-change for a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754005/how-to-implement-an-ng-change-for-a-custom-directive)

Comment: Also read this: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted ngTagsInput does not have any ng-change attribute as I saw, this is why you need scope watch in your directive controller.

Comment: Thanks this is I was looking,  Could you tell me why I was not able to call ng-change....

Comment: As I wrote in the previous comment, ngTagsInput doesn't have any ng-change attribute, so you cannot bind your own function on this attribute, because it not exits. You also missed to bind your `change` function in directive scope attribute so this was a problem too, because in this case you called an undefined function.

Comment: Is my approach right or not, Reason It that I just want to put on line in my Angularjs View...

Comment: One more, Demo suggested by you, function '$scope.selectUser ' is calling only one time..

Comment: Yeah you are right, something is wrong, sorry. Check @Anita's answer, she found out that ngTagsInput has `on-tag-added` attribute, which looks like to be a better solution. Anyway save my second link, because it's really helpful if you make custom directives and you need ng-change for it.

Comment: Thanks , could you tell me, is my approach is right or not. Reason Behind is that, In Angularjs View, I want to use auto-complete directive oneline, I want to make it as generic approach.

Comment: Yes, I think wrapping third-party directive into a custom directive is a good approach if you use this directive more times in your application in the same way and you want to shorten your code.