# Assign the value from one ng-model to another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have created a multiselect with autocomplete directive its mapping the selected list to the ng-model of the directive . I want to get a single field value from the ng-model and assign that to another ng-model . I am not able to do that . If I am passing the whole ng-model value and assigning to another ng-model its working fine but with single field value it is not working.

Please find the link to the fiddler for the code -

> https://jsfiddle.net/719x1rbs/11/l

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">


    <typeahead data-ng-model="selecteds" ng-change="emailId=selecteds.email" items="contacts" displaytag="name" displayitem="name">
    </typeahead>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="emailId" />
    {{emailId}}
  </div>
```

I am not able to run the code in fiddle but its a running code in my system.

Can anyone please help me on how I can pass one field in an ng-model to another ng-model.  In the  {{emailId}} I should be getting the value '@pacman.com'.

Comment: provide some more elaboration , what you want and where its gonna reflect the changes. @sonam

Comment: In the ng-model attached to the directive I am getting the values as an array. At the backend I do not want to send the complete array of the selected items. I just want to send like say in the above example the emailId so I am taking a hidden variable and mapping the ng-model value of the directive to this hidden variable ng-model onchange but its not working.  I want to pass the value in the backend as {'red@pacman.com','pink@pacman.com','cyan@pacman.com'} . Also I ahve attached the fiddler code for the same.

Comment: Ok, I got it, for one thing i wanna correct you its not "fiddler" its "fiddle" fiddler is some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem with your code is, you want to get email id from the selected items, by doing `selecteds.email` but `selecteds` is not a object with property `email` its a Array of selected objects. So you should use Two way binding property of Angular and directly use the `selecteds` Array of object and iterate it to get the separate Array of email Ids. On some specific event . Because in your case `ng-change` event not gonna fire every time value of Model will change because its a custom directive you can go through [Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754005/how-to-implement-an-ng-change-for-a-custom-directive). So make sure you fire a proper event for your need full.